# How to delete a Jelastic environment through the API?

Tags: api, jelastic

I tried to delete one of my Jelastic environments by means of the following API call:

```
curl -k \ 
-H "${CONTENT_TYPE}" \ 
-A "${USER_AGENT}" \ 
-X POST \ 
-fsS ${HOSTER_URL}/1.0/environment/control/rest/deleteenv -d "password=${password}&session=${session}&envName=${envName}
```

where I am sure that the `session` and `envName` are correct, as I have other commands running perfectly well with them. In particular, I get the `session` in the following way:

```
getSession() { 
  local login=$1 
  local password=$2 
  local hosterUrl=$3 
  echo "Signing in..." >&2 
  local cmd=$(curl -k -H "${CONTENT_TYPE}" -A "${USER_AGENT}" -X POST \ 
    -fsS "$hosterUrl/1.0/users/authentication/rest/signin" -d "login=$login&password=$password"); 
  exitOnFail $cmd 
  echo "Signed in" >&2 
  echo $(jq '.session' <<< $cmd | sed 's/\"//g') 
}
```

In the call to `deleteenv`, I provide the very same password as that of my Jelastic provider account. Indeed, when I want to delete an environment through Jelastic's dashboard, this is the password I need to provide to make the deletion happen. However, I get the following error:

```
{"result":801,"source":"hx-core","error":"invalid password"}
```

Because the password field is documented as optional in [Jelastic's API documentation](https://docs.jelastic.com/api/#!/api/environment.Control), I tried not to set the password. This yields the following error:

```
{"result":3,"source":"JEL","error":"invalid parameter [password] for method [DeleteEnv] in service [ControlService]"}
```

I tried to use other secrets as that password, like the `APPID`, without any success.

Does anyone have a clue what password I need to put there?

Comment: btw I am using Jelastic v.5.5.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We used the same oneliner [based on API](https://docs.jelastic.com/api/#!/api/environment.Control-method-DeleteEnv) you used, your script to get a session and the same Jelastic version but were not able to reproduce this issue. Environment were successfully deleted.

> Does anyone have a clue what password I need to put there?

This is the same password as you used to get session or to enter Dashboard. Make sure there are no additional symbols in your password variable.

> Because the password field is documented as optional

Indeed, it's optional if use [token](https://docs.jelastic.com/personal-access-tokens) instead of session. In case of session, password is an obligatory parameter.